# Javascript refuses to return anything

Tags: javascript, return

```
getGood = function(v,x) {
    $.getJSON('json/products.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (v.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase()) {
                $.each(val.products, function(ckey, cval) {
                    if (x.toLowerCase() == ckey.toLowerCase()) {
                        var dval=new Date().getDay();
                        var qHash=hex_md5(v+x+qs('cst')+dval).toLowerCase();    
                        if (qHash == qs('hash')) {
                            return dval;
                        } else {
                            window.location.replace('/errors/418.html');
                        }
                    }                
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var owner=getGood(qs('cat'),qs('subp'));
    alert(owner==null);
    $('.content_title').html(qs('subp'));
    $('.description').html(owner.descripion);
})
```

The above code is supposed to read a JSON file, compare some query strings to test for validity and then return the object if the request is valid.  Problem is, no matter what I do, `getGood` refuses to return any value to my `owner` variable.  I've tried having it return the different values around it.  I was just trying to get it to return anything I could.  It needs to return `cval`.  The alert at the bottom, however, always says "undefined/null".

**EDIT**

Because apparently people think I am just that retarded:

YES, it gets to the return statement.  Yes, qHash == qs('hash'), I'm not asking you to check every if/loop/etc. I already know all of that works.  I'm asking, why does my return statement not end up setting `owner` to what it is supposed to.

Comment: You got all these conditions. Ifs, loops... only in one case is a value returned. Just debug the code and see where it goes wrong. How should we guess from here?

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say that `qHash` does not equal `qs('hash')`.

Comment: Sorry you thought I thought you were retarded. Let me assure you I don't think you are.

Comment: @Golez, sorry, I was a bit annoyed that people were assuming things.  I thought I had explained it better in my post.  This was my fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback passed to "$.getJSON()" is executed **asynchronously**.  It is therefore just not possible to return a value from it.

Instead, pass in the code that needs to act on the value as a function parameter. The callback function can then pass the value **into** that function as a parameter.

```
function getGood(v, x, handleOwner) {
  $.getJSON('json/products.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          if (v.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase()) {
             $.each(val.products, function(ckey, cval) {
                if (x.toLowerCase() == ckey.toLowerCase()) {
                    var dval=new Date().getDay();
                    var qHash=hex_md5(v+x+qs('cst')+dval).toLowerCase();    
                    if (qHash == qs('hash')) {
                        handleOwner(dval); // calling the handler function here
                    } else {
                        window.location.replace('/errors/418.html');
                    }
                }                
            });
        }
     });
  });
}

//
getGood(qs('cat'),qs('subp'), function(owner) {
  alert(owner);
});
```

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly.  I didn't even think about that being the problem!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!  That's a really common pattern in JavaScript.

Comment: Not just because its asynchronous. The other callback functions may be synchronous, but they still won't make the main function return a value.

Comment: @GolezTroi yes that's quite true - the return is (was) buried down inside two "$.each()" calls.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript isn't "refusing to return" anything.  You're just not asking it to.

You're doing

```
var owner=getGood(qs('cat'),qs('subp'));
```

but `getGood` does not `return` any value.  The only `return` statement is in the `function (key, val)` inside `getGood` which returns from that function, not from `getGood`.

Comment: Ahhhh, good point too!  Pointy didn't mention this, I can see this as being another problem.  Luckily, Pointy's answer isn't hindered by this.  +1